# Write a query to get the sum of similar ids to display on each record

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I want to calculate the sum of the same ids and display in each record. expected Sample is given below

[image: Expectd result]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use Aggregate function in a Select statment without using Group By clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467216/is-it-possible-to-use-aggregate-function-in-a-select-statment-without-using-grou)

Answer (score 2):

Use analytics SUM():

```
SELECT
      Code, SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Code) as Value
  FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Summing over the window should allow you to maintain the overall sum for each record. `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` ensures that all values are taken into consideration

```sql
SELECT
   Code,
   SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY Code ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM
  mytable;
```

Comment: The `rows` component is redundant and typically left out.  That is why leftjoin's answer is preferred.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for this. I will have to check again with my current version of hive. Another user faced similar difficulties https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082057/hive-sum-over-a-specified-group-hiveql but I can investigate more